# Is there a glossary for all the acronyms of Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support

Maybe this question is a duplicate, but I'm not finding it in my searches.

There are several acronyms in several websites, such as: MMA, MWE, ...

I visit several sites, but as I visit some of these sites infrequently, I do not know what some people are commenting on.

Is there a glossary of this in the Help Center?

Comment: FYI, the TLA's are overloaded and so have environment/context specific meanings.  It's not realistic to list all the multiple overloads:(

Comment: I've never heard of any of these acronyms (in the context of Stack Overflow), either. Where are you seeing all of these?

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm not sure if it's in this Meta that I should ask. Is there a Meta superior to all the others? Something like Meta.SE? You have an excellent reputation. Could migrate this question?

Comment: Though I think ThingyWotsit is right and that if a glossary gets added it'd have to be a per site thing.

Comment: @BSMP I'm understanding. Is something particular to each site. I could have something in the help on a master site like StackExchange.

Comment: @BSMP Here is an example on the [TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80012/different-color-for-individual-bar-in-bar-chart-adding-bar-labels) website. What would MWE be? I think I'll only have the answer there.

Comment: If you actually bother to google it, you'll find it means Minimum Working Example.

Comment: Meals Wanting to be Eaten?   Not sure how Mixed Martial Arts is relevant to SO, unless it's to use in the edit wars..

Comment: @J.Steen Thank you. But this is just one example. If there were a list of the most common would be interesting. I've already made an requirements for the moderator to migrate my question to the appropriate site. I thank everyone.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I love the good humor of colleagues.

Comment: And my solution applies, quite magically, to most of the rest of the acronyms you can find, too.

Comment: @J.Steen Well then I'll have to create my own list myself. In my Brazilian language it's called `catadão`(slang).

Comment: I like the idea of a list of acronyms. However, the examples given here don't apply to Stack Overflow. Maybe they should be replaced with MCVE, NAA, VLQ..

Comment: It's unclear; are you talking about acronyms on *Stack Exchange* sites? Or just random sites on the internet?

Comment: @TylerH Stack Exchange sites. They're asking for a glossary of all the acronyms on SE sites.

Comment: I meant that each Stack Exchange site having it's own glossary may work better in case certain acronyms mean different things on multiple sites. So, for example, you would go to the TEX site's glossary to find out what MWE means and Stack Overflow's glossary to find out what MVCE means. It might be too difficult for Meta SE to try to maintain one list for all 100+ sites.

Comment: Before a lot of the other SE sites "graduated" into full sites and got full designs, their icons were often some 2-3 letter abbreviation.  I'm sure some of the sites got their abbreviations from there.  Don't know where you'd look them up though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not such a list in the Help Center, but there is one on Meta.SE

[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Keep in mind that only terms used in the context of the Stack Exchange network are listed there, and that list will not and should not expand to cover terms found on sites outside of the SE network. Use Google, Wikipedia, the [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=urban%20dictionary), or head over to a chatroom for those.

Comment: Oh, it already exists. Turns out there's a lot fewer SE specific terms than I thought.